# How to temporarily define a condition, within a block?

Tags: exception, conditional-statements, lisp, common-lisp, control-flow

In [Common Lisp](https://common-lisp.net/) (specifically [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/) in my case), it is common to define exceptions (known as "conditions") using the [define-condition](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_5.htm) macro. This defines the condition globally, within the current package.

Is there a way to define a condition *locally*, within a specific scope? Or, alternatively, some other idiomatic way to prematurely exit a scope with a value, without polluting the global namespace?

```
(with-conditions
  (block
    (...)
    (prematurely-exit-block-with some-data)
    (...))
  (when-condition-happens (some data) ...))
```

Comment: Apparently what I'm looking for is `throw`, `catch` and possibly `block` ;)

Comment: You may well be looking for `block` / `return-from`.

Comment: You almost always want lexical scoping (ie `block` or `tagbody`) rather than dynamic scoping (`throw` and `catch`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to define a condition locally, within a specific scope?

No.

> Or, alternatively, some other idiomatic way to prematurely exit a scope with a value, without polluting the global namespace?

Common Lisp has several constructs for such control flow, where one or more values are returned: `RETURN`, `RETURN-FROM`, `THROW`, ...

- `RETURN` returns from a *block* named `NIL`
- `RETURN-FROM` returns from a named *block*
- `THROW` jumps to a catch tag, which got established via `CATCH`

`return` and `return-from` are using lexical blocks. `catch` establishes a dynamic scope for its tag.

Comment: For the sake of anyone who finds this answer by search, I want to add that these mechanisms all return control flow up the stack however the regular Common Lisp condition system does not unwind the stack until a restart is invoked in the handler (although this feature appears to not be one the asker was looking for in this case).